# Non-linear optimization with unknown derivative and real numbers only

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

**Background** I'm trying to optimize a set of 7 parameters which are the core configuration of some external engine (specifically [Solr parameters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis)). 
I already have an optimization function which grades the results.

The **idea** was to use Nelder Mead because the derivative is unknown and there are probably few local optimums.

The **problem** is that the parameters must be real numbers and Nelder-Mead creates fractions.

My **questions**:

1) Is there a known way to overcome this problem?

2) Are there different optimizations I can use which address my problem?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Why is it a problem if you input rationals into a variable that takes reals?

Comment: Nelder mead adjusts the numbers by small fractions, if I round the value it will always use the same numbers.
It doesn't feel right using Nelder mead here (My problem is discrete not continuous)

Comment: Is the merit function fast to compute? If so, what about approximate the gradient by finite differences and use a gradient-based descent method?